# I am getting error while passing raw data to postman

Tags: php, postman, laravel-8

I am trying to upload an image in my database table but I am getting 200 ok when i try to send request through postman, but no data is updated in my database table. I write the add book operation in the BooksController there i add one if condition which will check the image part. In postman i make the content-type in header as application/json. please help me where i should edit in my code. here is a screenshot[image: screenshot]

`BooksController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\Books as BooksResource;
use App\Models\Books;
use App\Models\User;

class BooksController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function addBooks(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'author' => 'required|string|between:3,15',
            'title' => 'required|string|between:3,15',
            'description' => 'required|string|between:3,30',
            'quantity'=> 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    
           ]);
        $book=new Books();
        $book->price=$request->input('price');
        $book->title=$request->input('title');
        $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
        $book->author=$request->input('author');
        $book->description=$request->input('description');
        $book->user_id = auth()->id();    
        
        $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $path =$request->file('image')->store('/public/images');

        $book->name = $name;
        $book->path = $path;
        
        $book->save();
        return new BooksResource($book);
    }
}
```

`Books.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class Books extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'image',
        'price',
        'title',
        'quantity',
        'description',
        'author'   
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

`Books.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Books extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

`Books_migration_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('title');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

Comment: _“In postman i make the content-type in header as application/json”_ - that is not the correct content type for an actual HTTP file upload. It needs to be `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for your reply, I changed the content-type to multipart/form-data. But it sill showing the same error

Comment: Also, your image seems to be just a string of the local path on the client, not an actual  image.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow for your reply, should i hv to change the migration table image column. please suggest

Comment: You can not just change the header, and then still actually send JSON as the body content. Go read up on how to perform a proper HTTP file upload using postman, https://blog.postman.com/run-collections-with-file-uploads-using-newman/, and how to add other request parameters as well.

Comment: @SanchitaBarik no need to change your database design, but this way you do not upload any files, thus your code will fail. This question is really not about mysql, but about postman. Take heed of CBroe's comment and learn about how to simulate html file uploads with postman.

Answer (score -1):

```
$book->file=$request->file('file')->store('<folder name>')
```

I hope this will work

Comment: No it won't work. The issue is on the postman side, not on the server side. Read the comments below the question.

Comment: @Shadow, no it will work . it's store inside the local Directory

Comment: Again, the problem is not on the server side with the php script. Please, read the comments below the question!